# Why can we replace the Inverse with the Transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am learning about inverse kinematics, and the Jacobian method of solving it; however I am confused as to why/how we can estimate the inverse of the Jacobian in this equation with the transpose.
$$dO = J^{-1}V \rightarrow dO = J^TV$$
Here is the article I am reading from: https://medium.com/unity3danimation/overview-of-jacobian-ik-a33939639ab2

Comment: If the matrix is orthonormal the transpose is the inverse. Perhaps that answers your question.

Comment: Yes, I have researched that, however I do not think that it is always orthonormal.

Comment: If you read the sentence just before talking about the transpoe, it says:
"A rough approximation to the Jacobian Inverse that works in many simple cases is replacing the Jacobian Inverse with the Jacobian Transpose:"

So it is not exactly an equality. Moreover, it does not say **why** this is a good approximation. It depends on the context.

Comment: True, I will edit my question. I just want to know how this can approximate the inverse.